# How do I install drivers for the Alfa AWUS036H USB wireless adapter?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, hardware, realtek

I bought this network adapter from Amazon and I don't know how to install the drivers. The adapter comes with a CD for drivers and when I put it in, it has `.autorun.exe` `autorun.ico` `autorun.csp`, and `autorun.inf`.

I know that it supports Linux because when I installed them on my Windows (Dual-boot) it asked me if I wanted to Linux drivers, Mac, or Windows.

Answer (score 7):

The ALFA AWUS036H adapter is based on the Realtek RTL8187 chipset. The drivers should be built into Ubuntu, but you may want to try installing the latest from Realtek:

1. Download the *"Linux driver for Kernel 3.0.0/3.1.0/3.2.0"* from the Realtek website [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=1&Level=6&Conn=5&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true).
2. It will open in Archive Manager; extract the `rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012` folder to your *Downloads* folder.
3. Open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`, and type/paste the following, one line a time:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
   cd Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Then reboot, and your AWUS036H should be detected.

Comment: These drivers are not needed and will not build for new Ubuntu releases 14.04+

Comment: I found the driver here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/alfanetwork/files/Driver/