# Alpha RTL8187 drops connection on 14.04 (server)

Tags: wireless

My wireless connection keeps dropping after about 10 minutes. It seems to happen when I'm sshed into the machine, but it could just be coincidence.

Some of the things I've tried are turning off N on the router and adding [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453110/rtl8187-wireless-card-drops-signal-within-seconds) and [these suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288280/how-to-install-the-new-version-of-the-rtl8187-driver-on-ubuntu-13-04) to `rc.local`. Also, I was getting `No probe response ... after 500ms, disconnecting` previously (like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257144)).

I also tried to install the driver mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178009/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-alfa-awus036h-usb-wireless-adapter), but compiling it failed for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the output of `wireless_script`:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Mar 2015 17:15 EDT -0400

Booted last: 28 Mar 2015 17:11 EDT -0400

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-31-generic #43~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:13:38 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /home/james/.dmrc: No such file or directory
Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard [1043:8505]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04ca:0027 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1038:1369 Ideazon, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               179412  0 
eeepc_wmi              13151  0 
asus_wmi               24094  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
rtl8187                64924  0 
mac80211              652718  1 rtl8187
cfg80211              494330  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,rtl8187
eeprom_93cx6           13344  1 rtl8187
mxm_wmi                13021  0 
video                  20128  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    19193  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

p4p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'p4p1' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.163  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:caff:fe65:da32/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:937 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:494 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:429007 (429.0 KB)  TX bytes:73053 (73.0 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

p4p1      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"MW6L8"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'MW6L8' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=36 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-25 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:25  Invalid misc:13   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [MW6L8] -------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8187
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           36 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    C8J6H:           Infra, <MAC 'C8J6H' [AC2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 95 WPA2
    OurHouse:        Infra, <MAC 'OurHouse' [AC6]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 69 WPA WPA2
    Earth:           Infra, <MAC 'Earth' [AC3]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA2
    S7SRL:           Infra, <MAC 'S7SRL' [AC5]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA2
    YN440:           Infra, <MAC 'YN440' [AC4]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WEP
    O5PM1:           Infra, <MAC 'O5PM1' [AN6]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WEP
    *MW6L8:          Infra, <MAC 'MW6L8' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 94 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.163
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

- Device: p4p1 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'p4p1' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MW6L8]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MW6L8 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MW6L8 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]> | mtu=1280
[ipv4] method=manual
[ipv6] method=ignore

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

p4p1      no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'MW6L8' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-25 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MW6L8"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000001c959b265
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'C8J6H' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"C8J6H"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000788d979494
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'Earth' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Earth"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000360acc5d27
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'YN440' [AC4]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"YN440"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000015d8196d73
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'S7SRL' [AC5]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"S7SRL"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000ebbbea79d5
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'OurHouse' [AC6]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"OurHouse"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000012cea00422
                    Extra: Last beacon: 52ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
    lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

p4p1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
srcversion:     7F17406EFFE91762CB15EEE
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:63:E8:EF:0C:63:AB:DB:14:5F:D1:7C:AA:A9:7B:8C:69:73:45:84
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[rtl8187]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
license:        GPL
description:    RTL8187/RTL8187B USB wireless driver
author:         Larry Finger <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Hin-Tak Leung <htl10@users.sourceforge.net>
author:         Herton Ronaldo Krzesinski <herton@mandriva.com.br>
author:         Andrea Merello <andrea.merello@gmail.com>
author:         Michael Wu <flamingice@sourmilk.net>
srcversion:     DE5DF1BDA1FE2F1BDE67103
depends:        mac80211,eeprom_93cx6,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:63:E8:EF:0C:63:AB:DB:14:5F:D1:7C:AA:A9:7B:8C:69:73:45:84
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     D0CBADABD6F74A53B0BE7CC
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:63:E8:EF:0C:63:AB:DB:14:5F:D1:7C:AA:A9:7B:8C:69:73:45:84
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     88153DA7841870E4F2012EE
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:63:E8:EF:0C:63:AB:DB:14:5F:D1:7C:AA:A9:7B:8C:69:73:45:84
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 1
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi lln_disable=1 swcrypto=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 32M fixed 
sudo iwconfig wlan0 frag 2346
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rts 2347
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 27

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8187)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    8.297299] ieee80211 phy0: hwaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>, RTL8187vB (default) V1 + rtl8225z2, rfkill mask 2
[    8.305646] rtl8187: Customer ID is 0xFF
[    8.306028] rtl8187: wireless switch is on
[   10.153921] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   11.901720] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'MW6L8' [AC1]>
[   12.100265] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'MW6L8' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   12.101771] wlan0: authenticated
[   12.103474] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'MW6L8' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   12.105710] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'MW6L8' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[   12.106176] wlan0: associated
[   12.106187] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   12.158163] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'lln_disable' ignored

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Rtl8187 is a very bad chip for get a stable connection. It's indicated for pentesting and packet sniffing. For a stable connection Atheros is better. However this is my personal opinion.

Comment: Hmm ok, well it's what I have. I also don't have any issues when booting into Windows 7. As an update, I changed a few settings and haven't experienced a disconnect in a while. There is sometimes lag though and ssh connections drop, but at least I can reconnect. The settings are: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 16M fixed`, `sudo iwconfig wlan0 frag 512`, and `sudo iwconfig wlan0 rts 512`

Comment: Please, respond yourself with your answer and accept it for close the post.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this solved. I'm still getting lag, disconnects, and complete drops occasionally.

Comment: Did you read this question/answer (http://askubuntu.com/questions/453110/rtl8187-wireless-card-drops-signal-within-seconds)?

Comment: Yup (I linked it in the original question).