# ALFA AWUS036NH driver

Tags: wireless, make, alfa-wireless

hello everyone i have a question about ALFA AWUS036NH network adapter,
i tried this link: [How do I install drivers for the Alfa AWUS036H USB wireless adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178009/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-alfa-awus036h-usb-wireless-adapter)
but when i do:

```
make
```

i get these errors:

```
    make[2]: *** [/home/mohammad/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187/r8187_core.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mohammad/Downloads/rtl8187L_linux_1041.0209.2012/rtl8187] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What do I have to change to compile the driver?

Comment: Isn't rtl8187 already built in to Ubuntu with kernel version 3.8.0-xx? Is it not working as expected?

Comment: no it's not working :(
i have tried many way many things and everytime i stuck with unknown error i think if the driver installed correctly i think all of the problems will be solved

Comment: What is the error, exactly? What does this tell us? sudo modprobe rtl8187 and next: dmesg | grep rtl

Comment: chili555 your commands give me this: mohammad@dv6-Notebook:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8187
mohammad@dv6-Notebook:~$ dmesg | grep rtl
[ 2595.425680] rtl8187: `' invalid for parameter `and'
[ 2680.789038] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8187

Comment: It appears you have attempted a driver parameter. Let's see: ls /etc/modprobe.d. If you have a file relating to rtl8187, show us: cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8187.conf or whatever you found.

Comment: the command ls /etc/modprobe.d gives me: alsa-base.conf           blacklist-framebuffer.conf   blacklist-watchdog.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf   blacklist-modem.conf         vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
blacklist.conf           blacklist-oss.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf
and the command: cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8187.conf
 gives me: cat: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8187.conf: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

There is a newer rtl8187 here. I suggest you download this file to your desktop: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.12.2/backports-3.12.2-1.tar.bz2 Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

'make' takes a few minutes, so please be patient. Reboot and let us have your report. If it is not working as expected, post:

```
dmesg | grep rtl
```

Comment: it walks without any errors, is that mean the driver is successfully installed or i should do more things ?

Comment: Only do the things I mentioned, including reboot.