# Can't install drivers Alfa AWUS036H USB wireless adapter

Tags: alfa-wireless

I just recently re-installed Ubuntu 14.xx and when I proceeded to install Alfa AWUS036H drivers I failed, here is the error. By the way I checked out this thread
[ALFA AWUS036NH driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397717/alfa-awus036nh-driver)

they still did not helped me same old error. When I type "make" in terminal the error comes out:

```
/home/steroid/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/drivers/bcma/driver_gpio.c: In function ‘bcma_gpio_unregister’:
/home/steroid/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/drivers/bcma/driver_gpio.c:113:2: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  return gpiochip_remove(&cc->gpio);
  ^
/home/steroid/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/drivers/bcma/driver_gpio.c:114:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
make[6]: *** [/home/steroid/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/drivers/bcma/driver_gpio.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [/home/steroid/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/drivers/bcma] Error 2
make[4]: *** [_module_/home/steroid/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1] Error 2
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

UPDATE: When I plug in the adapter my OS freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit with kernel 3.13.0 using AWUS036H and also could not get the driver installed from Alfa. But my kernel default rtl8187 driver would work partially.  It would shut down periodically and I'd have to unplug/plug the WiFi device to restart it (`sudo modprobe -r rtl8187; sudo modprobe rtl8187` would also work).

Digging around I tried the backport drivers and it's been working great for over 8 hours. I tried 3.13 version but it wouldn't compile so I tried the latest at this time (3.18) and it worked. Here's some data to get you there:

Get your driver package from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/ (see the one I used below).

```
tar -xf backports-3.18.1-1.tar.gz 
cd backports-3.18.1-1/
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

Check if it worked:

```
$ modinfo rtl8187
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-74-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v3.18.1-0-g39ca484) using backports v3.18.1-1-0-g5e9ec4c
license:        GPL
description:    RTL8187/RTL8187B USB wireless driver
```