# Alfa AWUS036H problem in Ubuntu 16.04 32bit

Tags: alfa-wireless

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (32bit). Everything is working fine so far, but am unable to use Alfa AWUS036H USB wireless adapter. 
The Alfa card connects and disconnects immediately. At first I thought it might be the driver, then I downloaded the recent driver from the manufacturers' website and the driver won't compile in Ubuntu 16.04 (32bit).

I have tried so many trick to get it working all to no avail. 
Any help would be appreciated. I love Ubuntu so much...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to kernel versions, the driver we can get from the manufacturer is outdated. The solution is to get a [backport for your kernel version here from kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/)<sup>1</sup>

Open a terminal and assuming you downloaded the file to `~/Downloads` and its version number is 4.4.2.1 (replace as appropriate)

```
cd Downloads
tar xf backports-4.4.2.1*
cd ~/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

It will install a lot of things, including the rtl8187, which our Alfa adapter needs.

After the commands finish, reboot. Please note that this wireless card does not support the n-mode, so you may have to change it in your router to allow the b/g/n modes (I had a problem with this, after setting the wireless router and waiting a couple of minutes, everything worked fine).

<sup>1</sup>kernel version can be seen with `uname -r` (I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 with 4.4.0-34 kernel, but downloaded the 4.4.2-1 backport and it worked)

I got this solution from the following question, just slightly  updated it: [ALFA AWUS036NH driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397717/alfa-awus036nh-driver)