# Trouble updating drivers on my AWUS036H USB wireless card

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, compiling

I am following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178009/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-alfa-awus036h-usb-wireless-adapter) to update my Alfa card to the latest drivers. When I run the `make` command I get multiple errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any drivers for your wireless dongle. They are already included in Linux kernel.

You tried to install a very old driver that was needed when kernel did not support this device out of the box.

That old driver will not build for new kernels anyway.

Comment: I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some sintax errors, maybe a dot or dot-comma symbol is missing in the file, error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘rtl8187_usb_probe’ . As in any programming file, the problem could be near the beginning of the file.